# Text Box inside EditTemplate in a Datagrid is returns empty text

Tags: asp.net, textbox

i want to Capture the the Text Entered by a user when the update Command is Pressed taking into Consideration that i Changed the Edit and Update Command To be named Activate

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="Datagrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
    OnCancelCommand="Datagrid1_CancelCommand" OnEditCommand="Datagrid1_EditCommand"
    OnUpdateCommand="Datagrid1_UpdateCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
              <EditItemTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="width: 200px; white-space: nowrap;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reg_FullName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="width: 100px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_User" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reg_UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="width: 100px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_AddedAt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reg_ActivatedAt") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="width: 100px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_IsAct" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reg_IsActive") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="width: 100px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Days" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Okaz, DaysNum %>"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="width: 100px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Hello_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate></asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:EditCommandColumn CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Activate"
            UpdateText="Activate"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
```

Well and my code behind is :

```
protected void Datagrid1_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Datagrid1.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        try
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * from OkazRegisteration";
            Datagrid1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID;
            Datagrid1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Datagrid1_CancelCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Datagrid1.EditItemIndex = -1;
        try
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * from OkazRegisteration";
            Datagrid1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID;
            Datagrid1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Datagrid1_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Item.ItemType)
        {
            case ListItemType.EditItem:

                TextBox txt_Days = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("Hello_txt");
                Label lbl_User = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_User");

                SqlDataSource2.UpdateCommand = "Update OkazRegisteration set Reg_IsActive='True', Reg_ExpiryDays=" + txt_Days.Text + " , Reg_ActivatedAt='" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "' Where Reg_UserName='" + lbl_User.Text + "'";
                SqlDataSource2.Update();
                break;
        }
        try
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * from OkazRegisteration";
            Datagrid1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID;
            Datagrid1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

in the Datagrid1_UpdateCommand

The Text Value of the TextBox txt_Days is always empty

What am i doing wrong ??

I've done this kind of work for a really long time , but i cannot see the error this time

Please Help,

Regards.

Comment: You could use Text='<%# Bind() %>' to set the value from the textbox; it would be a lot simpler. Also, with the way you are building your SQL string, someone could destroy your database by submitting the wrong thing. But aside from that... not sure why you aren't seeing your text. Are you sure that the txt_Days is being found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I am binding my grid every time the page loads so that the text inside my text box is erased.

Hope that gives a hint to anyone faces the same issue