# Getting text out of textarea from a ASP.NET GridView update

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox, textarea

i'm loosing my mind. Using ASP.NET in a GridView, amongst other controls, I have the following:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Intention">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="IntentionInfo" Enabled="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="IntentionInfo" Enabled="false" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I would like to take the value out of this textarea and save in a database. However, server side, I try to pull the value out, like such:

```
string txt = (TextBox)DonationResultsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[1].Text;
```

... but I keep getting the value that was SENT to the Client.

I wrote this javascript and I can see the values change in the DOM, but still the server keeps taking the old value.

```
$("textarea").change(function()
{
    var txt = $(this).val();

    $(this).html(txt).text(txt);
});
```

So my guess was ViewState, but I disabled it for those controls, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="IntentionInfo" ViewStateMode="Disabled" Enabled="false" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
```

Still nothing! Any ideas?

Comment: Does the data show in the textbox? I don't see any bindings in your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use a hidden field and update it on text changed for the text area. You could do this with jQuery like this:

```
$("textarea[id$=tbTest]").change(function () {
                $("input[id$=hdnVal]").val($("textarea[id$=tbTest]").val());
            });
```

Then on the server side, you can retrieve the hidden field's value and save it to your database.

Comment: yea, the hack way i have down. I'm wondering if there is an "official" way of doing it. I'd prefer to do it right than to hack it all up.

Comment: So, if you enable viewstate for the textbox, it doesn't keep the value between postbacks? Viewstate should keep values between postbacks.

Comment: it does. I disabled ViewState because I wanted to try and see if perhaps the ViewState was the cause of not updating the value in a <textarea>.

Comment: here is what is funnier. I gave up screwing with this, so I decided that I'll just hack it up and run it. So I've been trying the hack of updating the value. ASP.NET still refuses to see the update value. I wonder if something else is wrong.

Comment: I'm curious whether your code is referring to the current value of the textbox in the ItemTemplate and not the value in the EditItemTemplate because you have both controls named the same thing.

Comment: Try renaming the EditItemTemplate's textbox control and see if that changes the behavior. When you call your server side code, be sure to get the value from the newly named textbox.

Comment: ok it's half way figured out. Any idea on how, instead of a <asp:BoundField>, I can use a <TextBox>??

Comment: You can still use <asp:TemplateField> and a <TextBox>, but instead of this code:
string txt = (TextBox)DonationResultsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[1].Text;
Try this:
string txt = ((TextBox)DonationResultsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("IntentionInfo")).Text;

Comment: ok, i figured out the problem. I am filling my TextBox during DataBound from a hidden field. So really my problem is deeper. I guess the question I should be asking is, how do I set that TextBox to be equal the value of the <asp:BoundField> data item?

Comment: I think you may be binding your GridView on each page load. You should only bind it on !IsPostBack. Check out this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135777/text-box-inside-edittemplate-in-a-datagrid-is-returns-empty-text

Comment: yea, that's what I was saying, but didn't write during our convo. Sorry. Anyhow, I kind of need to do so because I have a dropdown list and two <textarea>'s that need to be bound. Unless you know of a better way to get it done. 

One way I was thinking of doing it was updating the CELL that is represented by <asp:BoundField> using JavaScript. Than, even it if the table re-bound, it would pull from the cell, not from the TextBox.

Comment: @pcmantiker. Thanks for your help. In the end, I needed to have the onbind so that I can use <textarea>'s. I need them disabled on load and then enabled during edit, so I'm doing some complicated binding on load and I need them to bind everytime.

I solved this by adding a hidden textbox, since this is what you suggested, I marked it as the answer. Thanks for the conversation.

Comment: just to add another comment. The other alternative, and most definitely the better one, was to use the MS Ajax and update the updating row via AJAX, manually. However, this would mean a rewrite of everything.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help and you were able to get something working. Good luck with the rest of your project!